# Most efficient way to seach Python list of lists on multiple fields?

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a data structure which is a list of lists. Each of the sublists has 2 strings and a dictionary, so overall a structure like this:

```
[
  [ 'A', 'A1', { .... }],
  [ 'A', 'A2', { .... }],
  [ 'B'. 'B1', { .... }],
....
]
```

What I want to be able to do is find all the sub-lists where both the first two values match some criteria - eg where the first value is 'B' and the second is 'B1'; if this were a database table, the equivalent would be something like

```
Select * from whatever where column1 = 'B' and column2 = 'B1'
```

There may be multiple matches to this query

What's the best/most Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I think the better thing to do here is just rework to use a list of nested dictionaries

Comment: Should your output be a list like your input, just filtered?

Comment: You have to do a linear search

Comment: @Peter_Danneman: I originally had the structure as a dictionary with a key of a tuple of the two columns, but it made it really unwieldly to work with later in the code

Comment: @DocDriven - yes - in most cases I'm expecting 0 or 1 results. It's a crappy thing to have to do, as the speed of testing will get exponentially worse as the outer list grows, but there's never going to be more than 1000-1500 entries in the outer list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension would work here:

```
filtered = [mylist for mylist in mainlist if mainlist[0] == 'B' and mainlist[1] == 'B1']
```

You can then use a for each loop to print out the values of `filtered`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
arr = [
  [ 'A', 'A1', { "1" }],
  [ 'A', 'A2', { "2" }],
  [ 'B', 'B1', { "3" }],
]

matches = [sublist for sublist in arr if sublist[0] == 'B' and sublist[1] == 'B1']

for match in matches:
  print(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my_list = [
              [ 'A', 'A1', { .... }],
              [ 'A', 'A2', { .... }],
              [ 'B'. 'B1', { .... }],
              ....
          ]

results = []

for item in my_list:
    if item[0] == <criteria1> and item[1] == <criteria2>:
        results.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions `filter()` and `itemgetter()` (it must be faster than a listcomp):

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = [
    ['A', 'A1', {}],
    ['A', 'A2', {}],
    ['B', 'B1', {}],
]

itemget = itemgetter(0, 1)
result = filter(lambda x: itemget(x) == ('B', 'B1'), d)

for i in result:
    print(i)
# ['B', 'B1', {}]
```